# Rails - Object Not Getting Created From 'New' Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to Rails, can you check my code to see where I might be going wrong. I am attempting to create a Song object.

By looking at my SQLite File, I can see that no new songs are being created.

In views/songs/new.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>MusicDiscoveryApp</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
          <%= form_for(@song, :html => {:id => 'add-to-library', :method => :post}) do |f| %>
            <div class="item-info">
              <%= f.select :category_id, [['Pop', 1], ['Rock', 2], ['Rap', 3], ['Reggae', 4], ['Other', 5]] , {:prompt=>"Select A Category"}, :id=>"choose-category"%>
            </div>
              <div class="item-info">
                <%= f.text_field :name , :placeholder=>"Song Name"%>
            </div>
            <div class="item-info">
              <%= f.text_field :price, :placeholder=>"Price"%>
            </div>
              <div class="item-info">
                <%= f.text_area :details ,:placeholder=>"Details"%>
            </div>
            <div class="item-actions">
              <%= f.submit "Post to Songs Library", :class=>"add-song"%>
            </div>
          <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 'new' method from songs_controller.rb - it was automatically generated

```
  def new
    @song = Song.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @song }
    end
  end
```

The 'create' method from songs_controller.rb - also automatically generated

```
  def create
    @song = Song.new(params[:song])
  end
```

Thanks for your time, I hope you can explain to me what I did wrong here. Thanks once again.

Comment: `ActiveRecord`'s `new` method does not save the new record to the database.

Comment: @AlexWayne Just curious, why not? Are there any use cases of having new instances of objects without saving them?

Comment: Because you want to build object in memory before saving them, giving you a chance to manipulate it, maybe it won't pass validation, all sorts of reasons. Look at your `new` controller action, which makes an object for your form to render the properties of. You don't want to save that because it has no data yet.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Although, in the RailsForZombies source code, they never saved it /created it, and that seemed to work for some reason. Thanks for your help, @AlexWayne , it makes sense to me now

Answer (score 2):

The song isn't being saved. Add:

```
@song = Song.new(params[:song])
@song.save
```

to your controller create method or change new to create

```
@song = Song.create(params[:song])
```